# Clear Username Binding (Unable to automaticalli debug wcf service)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Recently I've read an article about own WCF binding with Username and Password authentication.

Here is an article: http://webservices20.blogspot.ru/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html.

This project "Clear Username Binding" works well. But the problem for me is that I want the WCF server to be host in WCF Service Host. (Like if you create in VS any service library from the template it will be run in WCF Service Host). I've done the next thing. I've created a new project (service library) and simply copy your service and contract to this new project. Then I copied the `app.config` `system.serviceModel` section and added referenced to `ClearUserNameBinding` project and MyUserNameValidator. That's all
Next, I run the client application. Everything was ok. WCF Service Host had been started and client application ended as I expected. But the problem is that now if I put a breakpoint somewhere in the service implementation (let it be somewhere inside of the EchoString function) and run again I always get a message in VS IDE "Unable to automatically debug WCFServiceLibrary". I really don't know what to do with this error and how to get rid of it, because I need the debugging to be available for me.

P.S. This error is appearing only when I use ClearUserNameBinding. If I use for example wsHttpBinding it works perfect. And of course I have `<system.web> <compilation debug="true" />`  turned on in my config file

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio put a breakpoint in the first line of the client and attach to the process "WCF service host". Then you could debug into its breakpoints. Not sure how to do it w/o attaching to another process.

Also you could try to use CUB not as a separate binding but as a custom binding. You will need to create the custom binding from code. Pseudo code:

```
var b = new CustomBinding();
b.elements.add(new TextEncodingElement())
b.elements.add(new SecurityElement() {SecurityMode="UsernameOverTransport"})
b.elements.add(new AutoSecuredHttpTransportElement())
```